# No echo appearing of text input and $_FILES variable

Tags: php, javascript

I want to know what is the correct way of display a text input in an echo in the code below because nothing is being outputted:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  window.top.stopVideoUpload(
    <?php echo $result; ?>,
    '<?php echo "<input name='vidid' type='text' value='$id'/> " . $_FILES['fileVideo']['name'] ?>'
  );
</script>
```

Another attempt that didn't work:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  return window.top.stopVideoUpload(
    <?php echo $result; ?>,
    '<?php echo "<input name='vidid' type='text' value='".$id."'/>" . $_FILES['fileVideo']['name']; ?>'
  );
</script>
```

**UPDATE:**

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  window.top.stopVideoUpload(
    <?php echo $result; ?>,
    '<?php echo "<input name='vidid' type='text' value='".$id."'/>" . $_FILES['fileVideo']['name']; ?>'
  );
</script>
```

The error I am recieving is: `syntaxError: missing ) after argument list.`

Comment: You're not trying to use PHP code in a JavaScript function, are you? If the PHP code only inserts static strings into you JS function, that's ok, but you can't actually "use" PHP when the JS function is executed.

Comment: @Pharaoh Its because im using an iframe to navigate back to the `stopVideoUpload` function. Before I included the text input, the echos worked fine, but when I try to include the text input, then it is not working

Answer (score 0):

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">return window.top.stopVideoUpload(<?php echo $result; ?>, <?php echo "<input name='vidid' type='text' value='$id'/> " . $_FILES['fileVideo']['name']; ?>');</script>
```

Comment: Hi, sorry for late reply. This did not work, yet no errors appearing

Comment: i think the problem is you are sending input text box as parameter in your code... so change it and try another way..

Comment: Wait a minute an error is now appearing in console, it is stating: `syntaxError: missing ) after argument list`. Even though it seems strange as I have brackets in there. Look at my update section in question